# How to correctly use resizebox in a revtex document?

Tags: equations, two-column, revtex

I am writing a report using *revtex4-1* with a two column style and I have an equation that is too big and I don't want to "cut" using *eqnarray*.

I tried using *resizebox* but it doesn't work for me. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[utf8,aps,pre,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}



\begin{equation*}
\resizebox{0.4\hsize}{!}{$\vec{F_v^i} = \sum_{j=1}^{N_1} k_1 (l_{ij} - l_1^0) \frac{\vec{r_{ij}}}{|\vec{r_{ij}}|} + \sum_{j=1}^{N_2} k_2 (l_{ij} - l_2^0) \frac{\vec{r_{ij}}}{|\vec{r_{ij}}|} + \sum_{j=1}^{N_3} \gamma \frac{\vec{r_{ij}}}{|\vec{r_{ij}}|}$}     
\end{equation*}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The equation is moved to the center of the page when I use *resizebox*. **What is the right way to use *resizebox* in this situation?**

Comment: How about `multline`?  Also you need package `graphicx` for `\resizebox`.

Comment: Never use `\hsize` in LaTeX (only exception: some tricks with `tabularx` that are explained in the manual).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make your MWE work, then add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to the preamble.  Otherwise `\resizebox` will not be defined.

I suggest using `multline` though.  I also adjusted the typography of the vectors, `\vec{r_{ij}}` → `\vec{r}_{ij}`.

```
\documentclass[aps,pre,reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{multline*}
  \vec{F}_v^i = \sum_{j=1}^{N_1} k_1 (l_{ij} - l_1^0) \frac{\vec{r}_{ij}}{|\vec{r}_{ij}|} \\
  + \sum_{j=1}^{N_2} k_2 (l_{ij} - l_2^0) \frac{\vec{r}_{ij}}{|\vec{r}_{ij}|} + \sum_{j=1}^{N_3} \gamma \frac{\vec{r}_{ij}}{|\vec{r}_{ij}|}
\end{multline*}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way of resizing the equation so it fits in one single line?

Comment: As I stated in the first line of the answer, add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}` (Don't do this! Break the lines properly as devised in my answer.)

Comment: I did, I forgot to add that to the mwe, but it still doesn't show what I want, the text gets into the second column overlapping the lipsum text.

Comment: Try `\linewidth` instead of `\textwidth`. (Again, don't do this!)